# What can cause my horrible download speeds?

Tags: wired-networking

I assembled a Windows 7 machine a few weeks ago, and now I noticed my download speeds are abysmal. Copying to this computer is about 150kbyte/sec, on a Gigabit LAN. Copying from it is fine.

- It is not an ISP issue, as LAN copy speeds have the same problem
- It is not a cable problem, the speed is the same on any cable
- It is not a router issue, because the other computers on the LAN have no similar problems, and I even changed the socket this computer is plugged into on the router
- It is not tied to a specific application, torrent, ftp and browser downloads are equally slow
- It is probably a driver issue, because after reinstalling the Ethernet driver the download speed went up to 500kbyte/sec for half a day
- Setting manual speed negotiation did not help either
- Installing Win 8.1 clean (not just upgrade) did not solve the issue

The NIC is a Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller according to the Device Manager. It came with the Asrock AM1B-ITX motherboard.
The drivers were provided with the motherboard, but I tried the default Windows ones and and the latest from AMD.

Update2: *I just loaded Puppy linux, and the copy speeds were great were great for the first half hour. After that, the same behavior.

Comment: Perhaps the cable or connectors are faulty?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write that I tried that as well.

Comment: It doesn't look like a driver problem. What about malware? Or maybe someone is downloading on another PC?

Comment: Malware is possible, what is the best way to check?

Comment: If the speeds are OK with PuppyLinux, then you have definitely a problem with your ethernet driver.
You should play around with the driver settings and see if that helps. Sometimes the auto speed negotiations go awry, so it's best to set them manually.

Comment: And where do I set them?

Comment: Right-click on the Local Area Connection device in Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections.
Go to Properties.
Click Configure.
Go to Advanced tab.
Look for "Speed and Duplex"

Comment: What is your NIC ? What driver are you using ?

Comment: That would probably not solve the problem but since your NIC's manufacturer is Realtek, you could try downloading their drivers directly. http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/ → Communications Network ICs → Network Interface Controllers → 10/100/1000M Gigabit Ethernet → PCI Express → Software then choose mirror in row 1 or 2 depending on the OS.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same problem under Windows 7 x64 with a AM1B-ITX. Have you been able to solve it?

Comment: Your problem could be your drive is faulty or defragmentated. You would be amazed that you can end up with 15 % deframentation when just installing windows.
Does the speed differ if you move many small or very large files?
I know that I might sound like a computer store clerk now; but you don't have any other harddisk to try with?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on the Local Area Connection device in Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections.

Go to Properties, click Configure. Go to the Advanced tab.

Look for "Speed and Duplex"
Experiment with different values. As Jakke points point, "Auto" on this screen can sometimes go wrong. It may be some other setting on this Advanced tab needs tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

It was an unspecified hardware issue, the retailer returned my mony after sending the motherboard back to the manufacturer for investigation.